# Sorting with limited stack operations

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am working on a sorting machine, and to minimize complexity, I would like to keep the moving parts to a minimum. I've come to the following design:

- 1 Input Stack
- 2+ Output Stacks
- When starting, machine already knows all the items, their current order, and their desired order.
- The machine can move one item from the *bottom* of the input stack to the *bottom* of an output stack of its choice.
- The machine can move *all* items from an output stack to the *top* of the input stack. This is called a "return". (In my machine, I plan for this to be done by the user.)
- The machine only accesses the bottom of a stack, except by a return. When a stack is returned to the input, the "new" items will be the last items out of the input. This also means that if the machine moves a set of items from the input to one output, the order of those items is reversed.

The goal of the machine is to take all the items from the input stack, and eventually move them all to an output stack in sorted order. A secondary goal is to reduce the number of "stack returns" to a minimum, because in my machine, this is the part that requires user intervention. Ideally, the machine should do as much sorting as it can without the user's help.

The issue I'm encountering is that I can't seem to find an appropriate algorithm for doing the actual sorting. Pretty much all algorithms I can find rely on being able to swap arbitrary elements. Distribution/external sorting seems promising, but all the algorithms I can find seem to rely on accessing multiple inputs at once.

Since machine already knows all the items, I can take advantage of this and sort all the items "in-memory". I experimented with "path-finding" from the unsorted state to the sorted state, but I'm unable to get it to actually converge on a solution. (It commonly just gets stuck in a loop moving stacks back and forth.)

Preferably, I would like a solution that works with a minimum of 2 output stacks, but is able to use more if available.

Interestingly, this is a "game" you can play with standard playing cards:

- Get as many cards as you would like to sort. (I usually get 13 of a suit.)
- Shuffle them and put them in your hand. Decide how many output stacks you get.
- You have two valid moves:

  - You may move the *front-most* card in your hand and put it on top of any output stack.
  - You may pick up *all* the cards in an output stack and put them at the *back* of the cards you have in hand.
- You win when the cards are in order in an output stack. Your score is the number of times you picked up a stack. Lower scores are better.

Comment: Knuth vol.2 "Sorting and Searching" has a tape-to-tape polyphase merge sort that may be what you need.

Comment: After picking up the stack do the replaced items come out right away, or later?  And do they come out in their original order or reversed?  The way that I understood your game is different than the original description.  My understanding of your original description was "reversed" and "right away".  My understanding of your game was "reversed" and "delayed".  Note that "right away" and "reversed" with a single stack makes this into a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting problem.

Comment: @btilly I've edited the question to clarify how the machine accesses the stacks.

Comment: I don't think the polyphase merge sort will work as written, since it relies on merging multiple inputs, and I can only access one input at once. But I'm still reading, and it *is* a fun read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in `O(log(n))` returns of an output to an input.  More precisely in no more than `2 ceil(log_2(n)) - 1` returns if `1 < n`.

Let's call the output stacks A and B.

First consider the simplest algorithm that works.  We run through them, putting the smallest card on B and the rest on A.  Then put A on input and repeat.  After `n` passes you've got them in sorted order.  Not very efficient, but it works.

Now can we make it so that we pull out 2 cards per pass?  Well if we had cards 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, ... in the top half and the rest in the bottom half, then the first pass will find card 1 before card 2, reverse them, the second finds card 3 before card 4, reverses them, and so on.  2 cards per pass.  But with 1 pass with 2 returns we can put all the cards we want in the top half on stack A, and the rest on stack B, return stack A, return stack B, and then start extracting.  This takes `2 + n/2` passes.

How about 4 cards per pass?  Well we want it divided into quarters.  With the top quarter having cards 1, 8, 9, 16, ....  The second quarter having 2, 7, 10, 15, ....  The third having 3, 6, 11, 14, ....  And the last having 4, 5, 12, 13, ....  Basically if you were dealing them you deal the first 4 in order, the second 4 in reverse, the next for in order.

We can divide them into quarters in 2 passes.  Can we figure out how to get there?  Well working backwards, after the second pass we want A to have quarters 2,1.  And B to have quarters 4,3.  Then we return A, return B, and we're golden.  So after the first pass we wanted A to have quarters 2,4 and B to have quarters 1,3, return A return B.

Turning that around to work forwards, in pass 1 we put groups 2,4 on A, 1,3 on B.  Return A, return B.  Then in pass 2 we put groups 1,2 on A, 3,4 on B, return A, return B.  Then we start dealing and we get 4 cards out per pass.  So now we're using `4 + n/4` returns.

If you continue the logic forward, in 3 passes (6 returns) you can figure out how to get 8 cards per pass on the extract phase.  In 4 passes (8 returns) you can get 16 cards per pass.  And so on.  The logic is complex, but all you need to do is remember that you want them to wind up in order ... 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.  Work backwards from the last pass to the first figuring out how you must have done it.  And then you have your forward algorithm.

If you play with the numbers, if `n` is a power of 2 you do equally well to take `log_2(n) - 2` passes with `2 log_2(n) - 4` returns and then take `4` extraction passes with `3` returns between them for `2 log_2(n) - 1` returns, or if you take `log_2(n) - 1` passes with `2 log_2(n) - 2` returns and then `2` extraction passes with `1` returns between them for `2 log_2(n) - 1` returns.  (This is assuming, of course, that `n` is sufficiently large that it can be so divided.  Which means "not 1" for the second version of the algorithm.)  We'll see shortly a small reason to prefer the former version of the algorithm if `2 < n`.

OK, this is great if you've got a multiple of a power of 2 to get.  But what if you have, say, 10 cards?  Well insert imaginary cards until we've reached the nearest power of 2, rounded up.  We follow the algorithm for that, and simply don't actually do the operations that we would have done on the imaginary cards, and we get the exact results we would have gotten, except with the imaginary cards not there. 
 So we have a general solution which takes no more than `2 ceil(log_2(n)) - 1` returns.

And now we see why to prefer breaking that into 4 groups instead of 2.  If we break into 4 groups, it is possible that the 4th group is only imaginary cards and we get to skip one more return.  If we break into 2 groups, there always are real cards in each group and we don't get to save a return. 
 This speeds us up by 1 if n is `3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, ...`.

Calculating the exact rules is going to be complicated, and I won't try to write code to do it.  But you should be able to figure it out from here.

I can't prove it, but there is a chance that this algorithm is optimal in the sense that there are permutations of cards which you can't do better than this on.  (There are permutations that you can beat this algorithm with, of course.  For example if I hand you everything in reverse, just extracting them all is better than this algorithm.)  However I expect that finding the optimal strategy for a given permutation is an NP-complete problem.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! I've been able to "win" the card game for a while, but mostly through brute force, so I knew it was possible. I've tested your algorithm by hand, and it does indeed seem to be pretty good. I'll need to write some code to really put it to work of course. :)

Comment: @jpfx1342 You're welcome.  I improved the answer significantly by needing at most 4 extraction passes requiring 3 returns on extraction.  This saved roughly `log_2(n)` returns.

Comment: Yep, this is great. I've got a working version made, it automatically determines the split patterns based on the number of passes, and seems to work perfectly. I can even have it print out the "move list" for a permutation and then follow it by hand. It can also scale up to use more stacks if available. (Though that might not actually reduce the number of returns. It can complete in less passes, but each used stack forces a return. It also throws off the "expected returns" and such math, but that's probably my fault.)